# How to replace DataFrame.append with pd.concat to append a Series as row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with numeric values, such as

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

and I append a single row with all the column sums

```py
totals = df.sum()
totals.name = 'totals'
df_append = df.append(totals)
```

Simple enough.
Here are the values of `df`, `totals`, and `df_append`

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

>>> totals
A    4
B    6
Name: totals, dtype: int64

>>> df_append
        A  B
0       1  2
1       3  4
totals  4  6
```

Unfortunately, in newer versions of `pandas` the method `DataFrame.append` is deprecated, and will be removed in some future version of `pandas`.  The advise is to replace it with `pandas.concat`.

Now, using `pd.concat` naively as follows

```py
df_concat_bad = pd.concat([df, totals])
```

produces

```
>>> df_concat_bad
     A    B    0
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  3.0  4.0  NaN
A  NaN  NaN  4.0
B  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

Apparently, with `df.append` the `Series` object got interpreted as a row, but with `pd.concat` it got interpreted as a column.

You cannot fix this with something like calling `pd.concat` with `axis=1`, because that would add the totals as column:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, totals], axis=1)
     A    B  totals
0  1.0  2.0     NaN
1  3.0  4.0     NaN
A  NaN  NaN     4.0
B  NaN  NaN     6.0
```

(In this case, the result looks the same as using the default `axis=0`, because the indexes of `df` and `totals` are disjoint, as are their column names.)

How to handle this (elegantly and efficiently)?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to convert `totals` (a `Series` object) to a `DataFrame` (which will then be a column) using `to_frame()` and next *transpose* it using `T`:

```py
df_concat_good = pd.concat([df, totals.to_frame().T])
```

yields the desired

```
>>> df_concat_good
        A  B
0       1  2
1       3  4
totals  4  6
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `df.loc()` to solve this problem than `pd.concat()`

`df.loc["totals"]=df.sum()`